# Computing the eigenvalue of an operator in second quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, fermions, mathematics, many-body

At the moment I am reading a specific paper: "Effective pair interaction between impurity particles induced by  a dense Fermi gas" by David Mitrouskas and Peter Pickl.

I am wondering about a certain step, where the authors computed an eigenvalue: Let
$$\Omega_0=\bigwedge_{k\in B_F}\varphi_k \in \mathcal{H}^-_N \, ,\quad \varphi_k(x)=\frac{1}{L^{d/2}} e^{ikx}\in L^2([0,L]^d)\, ,$$
with $N=\vert B_F\vert$, $B_F=\{k\in (2\pi/L)\mathbb{Z^d}\colon \vert k \vert\leq k_F\}$ being the Fermi ball, and $L>0$.
The paper now states:

Since $a_l^*a_k\Omega_0$ is an eigenstate of the operator $T=\sum_k k^2 a_k^*a_k$ with eigenvalue $\left(\sum_{k\in B_F}k^2\right)+l^2-k^2$ it holds that for $E_0=\sum_{k\in B_F}k^2$
$$(T-E_0)a_l^*a_k\Omega_0=(l^2-k^2) a_l^*a_k\Omega_0\,.$$

On a heuristic level I understand why this equation should be correct, since the left-hand-side describes the relative kinetic energy. But I wondered how one would compute this equation when not knowing the eigenvalues?

Comment: Which paper, author, references...?

Comment: @TobiasFünke "Effective pair interaction between impurity particles induced by a dense Fermi gas" by David Mirouskas and Peter Pickl

Comment: Sorry, its "Mitrouskas"

Comment: Just use the canonical commutation relation between the creation/annihilation operators.

Comment: @MengCheng you mean by inserting a zero, like $$a_k a_l + a_l a_k $$?

Comment: This is confused. If $a_l^*a_k\Omega_0$ is an operator, it cannot be an eigenstate of $T$.  Eigenstates are states, not operators.  See the comment by @MengCheng to help you with the calculational details.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Why do you think it is an operator? It is a state. Is it the title that is confusing you?

Comment: @TobiasFünke well $T=\sum_k k^2 a_k^*a_k$ is an operator... so which would $a_l^* a_k\Omega_0$ be a state?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes, $T$ is an operator and $a_l^* a_k\Omega_0$ is a state; and, as claimed in the post, an eigenstate of $T$ for the eigenvalue given there. Sorry, I don't see what you mean, but that's okay, because OP should clarify. Although, to add, if $k$ in the expression for the state is not in $B_F$, I guess it is the zero vector (and by definiton not an eigenvector). And even if $k\in B_f$: if $l\neq k$ and $l\in B_F$, the state is the zero vector too...

Comment: @TobiasFünke ok I get it: $\Omega_0$ is a state, not a scalar.  But then what is $a_l^* \varphi_k$?  Does it ladder up to $\varphi_{k+l}$? This is where you thank Dirac for carefully distinguishing between functions, operators and states.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Ok, glad we agree now. $a^*_l$ is defined on the Fock space and its action is defined in the cited paper, section 2.1 (too long for a comment). This is actually a common notation in many-body (condensed-matter) physics, although the more "mathematically minded" community uses this only. If you want, you can write (possibly up to some constant) $\Omega_0 =|n_1,n_2,n_3,\ldots\rangle$, where $n_k=0,1$ and then the action of the creation and annihilation operators can be seen more clearly (see also below eq.33). The occupation number basis is more often used (in my experience).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Okay, to be honest the paper is more complicated since it considers also another tensor product. If you are (still) interested, have a look [here](https://web.math.ku.dk/~solovej/mbnotes), chapter 6.

Comment: @uzizi_1 Here are some hints. Let's define $n_k=a_k^\dagger a_k$ as the particle number. Using the canonical commutation relation $\{a_k, a_k^\dagger\}=1$, you can show that $[n_k, a_k]=-a_k$ (which just means $a_k$ annihilates a particle). Then you need to show your $\Omega_0$ is an eigenstate of $n_k$ as well, which should follow from definition.